# Visual Studio C# Triple Slash Indentation Preferences (///)

Tags: visual-studio, xml, c#, visual-studio-2017

Whenever I type `///`, it always auto generates the following.

```cs
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
```

This is actually *really* convenient, but I would like to modify this indentation a tad.  Instead, whenever I type, `///`, I would like Visual Studio to generate:

```cs
/// <summary> </summary>
```

Are there any preference options for me to do this in Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 0):

I had looked into both VS 2017 and VS 2019 and there is no option to achieve what you want.